# How does the textbox + button actually do the searching in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, button, textbox

I was just curious as to how the textbox + button search actually performs the search to fill up my gridviews, because I couldn't see anywhere that causes the databounds or anything. Is it a post-back thing? How does it work?! o.o

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SearchBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Search" />
```

Thanks heaps :)

Comment: can you be more specific

Comment: Look inside your `Button1_Click` method?

Comment: Gah - epic fail. I meant to have put the input field in there. Editing accordingly.

Comment: @COLDTOLD I guess I want to know the role of the input field and what function it performs. Does it do a postback? Does it cause all the GridViews to databind?

Comment: There is none. At least, none which reference either of these two controls. The only thing there is the Page_Load, which only checks if you are logged in or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magic binding between a textbox called "searchbox" and a "submit" button in asp.net. The work has to be done somewhere and it's probably just hidden away in some part of the project that you cannot easily find.

In this case, it seems like a normal postback is occurring and some logic in the code behind is interrogating the "SearchBox"'s .Text property.

Just do a project wide search on SearchBox.Text, you should be able to find where the logic is.

Comment: Alrighty - it's good to know that it's not just something done automatically that I didn't know about. Thanks! :)